# gcc cross compiler generates ___main instead of _main

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, cross-compiling

I am building cross-compiler for a new architecture, but when compiling a simple c code like the following:

```
int sum(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    int z=sum(2,3);
    return 0;
}

int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b; 
}
```

I am getting the following assembler code:

```
.text
    .global _main
_main:
    push fp
    mov fp, sp
    jmp 2
    call ___main
    limm r0, 3
    push r0
    limm r1, 2
    push r1
    call _sum

    ...
    ...

    ret

    .global _sum
_sum:
    push fp
    mov fp, sp

    ...
    ...

    ret
```

When trying to assemble the code, it raises an error wrong argument for **call ___main**, but it works fine for the other labels which have just one underscore (like _sum).

Now, my question is: is there any way how I can change the assembler output, so that it will output *call _main* (any macro or something else in the compiler files)?

I have read quite a lot about this error, and it says that *call _main* and *call ___main* are part of the C library setup and have the same address (which is true), but my assembler is not letting it through.

I am using GCC version 5.3.0 for the cross compiler.

Comment: There's something wrong with your assembler if you're getting an error from the assembler about `call ___main`. Changing it to `call _main` won't fix the problem, as that would cause an infinite recursive loop. Notice how `_main` is defined earlier the assembly code. The assembly function `___main` is a C++ library initialization function, the assembly function `_main` is the C function `main`.

Comment: Also, any modern configuration shouldn't _need_ to generate `call ___main`; the work it would do (e.g. running C++ global constructors) is taken care of with magic ELF sections instead.  The assembly generated looks suspiciously like 16-bit `a.out`-format x86 code, none of which things should be true for a "new architecture".  Are you writing this cross compiler's back-end yourself?  If so, I strongly recommend cribbing from the aarch64 back-end rather than the x86 back-end; aarch64 is ELF-based and hasn't accumulated decades of cruft.

Comment: If you're _not_ writing the cross-compiler yourself, the problem is likely to be that you (or whoever you got it from) built GCC incorrectly. It would really help if you told us the `config.sub` triplet for the architecture you're trying to build for. (If you have no idea what a `config.sub` triplet is, suspend what you're doing immediately and find out; this is a concept you must understand to work with GCC-style cross compilers.)

Comment: I added `jmp 2` instruction in main's prologue so it won't fall into an infinite loop. Now I'm trying to find out what generates the `call ___main` instruction.

Comment: @vaskog It sounds like you are writing this back-end yourself, so I'll tell you that you need to define `INIT_SECTION_ASM_OP` in your `tm.h`, and that the specific section of the [internals manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/) that you missed is "[How Initialization Functions Are Handled](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Initialization.html)". You should make time to read the internals manual cover to cover; if you read it already, read through it again. To successfully write a GCC back end you basically need to know the internals manual by heart.

Comment: @vaskog Also, if you are not already using ELF, you should __immediately__ switch to ELF.  Everything will work better.